# TYPO3 compression only works on js/css, not on html file itself

Tags: compression, typo3, pagespeed, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to optimize the pagespeed and trying to figure out what does what.
I've managed to merge and compress js/css files, so Google Pagespeed doesn't bother me with that anymore.
Now I still get the message that I can save some bytes by compressing "http://yourpage.com/" which basically means that the html/php-file itself is not compressed (I think)
Any idea how I can solve this?

Some additional information:
Using TYPO3 6.2.21 with the default .htaccess file enabled.

Answer (score 4):

there is an extension for that: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sourceopt
That works very well. I use it in many projects.

Comment: Apparently my htaccess had one too many conditions which prevented compression. Not sure if that makes sense since other files were compressed, but it works now.

Comment: Is it allowed by licence to remove the TYPO3 header commend (as this extension does)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to remove the '<IfModule mod_filter.c>' condition from my .htaccess file, now it's working. I read that my Apache version might be too old.